# Completly break out of post request while being in forEach() function

Tags: javascript, post, foreach, backend

The code below is an extract of a try catch block of a node.js backend. I want to break out of the complete post request if an item of the `req.body` is missing. I think right now the `return res` only breaks out of the `forEach()` function which results in the [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] error because it's sending another response later on.

```
Object.values(req.body).forEach(value=>{
  if (!value) {
    return res
      .json({
        message: "You are missing personal information.",
        success: false
      })
      .status(500);
  }
});

// stop this code from running
function generateUser(name) {
  const {doc, key} = new Document(KeyType.Ed25519)
      
  return {
    doc,
    key,
    name,
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

"There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool."

So you can't use a forEach-loop the way you're trying to and instead should use sth. like `Array.prototype.find`, for example like so:

```
const reqIsIncomplete = Object.values(req.body).find(value => !value);

if (reqIsIncomplete) {
    return res
      .json({
        message: "You are missing personal information.",
        success: false
      })
      .status(500);
}
```